# Where should I break a long line in Python

Tags: python, line, long-integer, break, code-formatting

I have this long line in my Python code:

```py
long_variable_name = [int(name) for name in long_variable_name] if long_variable_name else None
```

What is the proper way to break it to be less than 80 character wide?

Comment: Honestly: The length is ok. We don't have terminals anymore, so 100 - 110 chars are reasonable.
If you want to improve the line, refactor the list comprehension into a function with a name which explains what it'S doing

Comment: you could parenthesise the expression to break it wherever you want: `long_variable_name = ([int(name) for name in long_variable_name]
if long_variable_name else None)`

Comment: According to the [google python style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html?showone=Conditional_Expressions#Conditional_Expressions) which you may or may not regard as helpful conditional expressions not fitting in a single line should be refactored into full `if` statements.

Comment: There are multiple Python style guides. There's the Google one which @PaulPanzer linked, there's [PEP 8](https://pep8.org/ "pep8.org, unofficial but well-formatted copy of PEP8"), any company probably has there own. They might tell you that you can use longer lines, or where to break the lines, or various other options. A good default is PEP 8 if you don't have a reason to use a different style guide, because it's what the Python Foundation recommends.

Comment: @Daniel H, I want to format the code according to PEP 8, but I didn't find any hint to breaking this type of construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up formatting the code this way:

```py
long_variable_name = [
    int(name) for name in long_variable_name] if long_variable_name else None
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really a matter of opinion, but if you're going to make two lines of it anyway, I find the following more expressive:

```
if long_variable_name:
    long_variable_name = [int(name) for name in long_variable_name]
else:
    long_variable_name = None
```

Inline `if..else` statements read the wrong way round to me as a human, since the condition comes in between the two possible assignments.

An alternative is to ask forgiveness rather than permission:

```
try:
    long_variable_name = [int(name) for name in long_variable_name]
except TypeError:
    long_variable_name = None
```

Which might be what you need if you're not sure that `long_variable_name` is iterable. (You can also catch `ValueError` if you think any of the elements of `long_variable_name` might not be convertible to `int`s).
`

Comment: who says that `long_variable_name` is originally `None` ? it could be 0 or `""` or `[]`. This is not equivalent

Comment: Yes, you're right, I've corrected the `if` statement. This would be a comment but for the difficulty of formatting code in comments.

Comment: sorry but it's still not equivalent. Should have an else part to set `long_variable_name` to `None`. Besides, you're telling basically that ternary expressions are unreadable. That's your opinion.

Comment: Although I agree with your opinion regarding the readability, I didn't want to change the construct. I just want to break it into multiple lines.